# concept constraints don't apply

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I've the following code

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept has_id = requires(T) {
    T::Id;
    std::same_as<uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;
};
```

The `has_id` concepts ensure that a type has the member `Id` with type `uint8_t[16]`.

However, when writing the following example it works even though the `Id` has type `uint8_t[17]` which is invalid.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class Sample
{
public:
    static constexpr uint8_t Id[17] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,10,11};
};

template<has_id T>
void print_id()
{
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::hex);

    std::cout << "{" << (int)T::Id[0];

    for(auto i=1; i < sizeof(T::Id); ++i)
        std::cout << ", " << (int)T::Id[i];

    std::cout << "}";
}

int main()
{
    print_id<Sample>();

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried it on Visual C++ 2022 17.3 and Clang 14 and they give the same result, any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class T>
concept has_id = requires(T) {
    T::Id;
    std::same_as<uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;
};
```

Confirms that the expression `T::Id` compiles, and that the expression `std::same_as<....>` compiles. It doesn't check whether the latter is `true` or `false`.

You can just write

```
template <class T>
concept has_id = requires(T) {
    T::Id;
    requires std::same_as<uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;
};
```

to change the constraint from *must compile* to *must be true*.

---

**Note** GCC 12 helpfully emits the following warning with your original code:

```
<source>:7:2: warning: testing if a concept-id is a valid expression;
  add 'requires' to check satisfaction [-Wmissing-requires]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version which is more simple then other answers:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept has_id = std::same_as<const uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;
```

Note also extra `const` you (and others) have missed in expression.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tszz4hxxj)

Comment: True, and much terser, although the compile error isn't quite as friendly if the member `Id` is missing (or misspelled)

Comment: Thank you, once the code compiled I noticed it

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your requirement just checks that `std::same_as<uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;` compiles. You want to use [nested requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires#Nested_requirements) to require that the *value* of `std::same_as<...>` is actually `true`. A fixed requirement would look like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
concept has_id = requires(T) {
    T::Id;
    requires std::same_as<uint8_t[16], decltype(T::Id)>;
};
```